# For which html5 attributes is the "empty attribute syntax" allowed?

Tags: html, syntax, attributes

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty says

> #### Empty attribute syntax
>
> Certain attributes may be specified by providing just the attribute name, with no value [… which] is exactly equivalent to specifying the empty string as the value for the attribute.

IIRC, boolean attributes often use this. However, what does "*certain* attributes" refer to? **In which attributes, on which elements, is this syntax allowed?** Or: where is it not allowed?

I could not find a complete list anywhere.

Comment: Apparently, the http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup that I quoted **is not HTML5**. Hrmpf.

Comment: Well it was going to be a reference of some sort, not unlike the list you were seeking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The empty attribute syntax is just a shorthand for an attribute with a name and an empty-string value, and doesn't mean anything special on its own. So, other than boolean attributes, any attribute that permits empty values, including `class`, can be specified with empty attribute syntax, and any attribute that doesn't permit empty values, such as `id` and `type`, cannot be specified with empty attribute syntax.

You can confirm this by comparing the validation results of the following snippets using [Validator.nu](http://validator.nu).

Both of the following snippets should validate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><title>Test</title>
<body class>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html><title>Test</title>
<body class="">
```

And both of the following snippets should produce the same validation error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><title>Test</title>
<body id>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html><title>Test</title>
<body id="">
```

> Error: Bad value for attribute `id` on element `body`: An ID must not be the empty string.

Comment: Hm. Why would the spec explicitly distinguish between "*… or `""` (empty string) or [empty](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty)*" then?

Comment: @Bergi: I am not sure. I generally ignore /TR/html-markup now because it has been abandoned by the HTMLWG. (For whatever reason, they don't state or even so much as indicate this on every page, just the [landing page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup).)

Comment: Oh dang, seems Google doesn't know about that and referred me to it nonetheless. And when I check the equivalent section at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0 - oh wonder! - the phrase "*Certain attributes …*" is no more there. Thank you!