# Is alt the same as alt=""?

Tags: html, attributes, seo, screen-readers, alt

I'm adding `alt` attributes to all my images to improve SEO/screen reader performance.

Per best practice, images that are purely aesthetic should have an empty alt attribute `alt=""`so screen readers skip over them. I'm in WordPress and noticed it does add `alt` to these descriptionless aesthetic images, but not `alt=""`.

Does `alt` get read the same as `alt=""` by screen readers and search engine crawlers, or should I go in and programatically force an `alt=""`?

Comment: I think that's a stretch - sure SEO is involved but it's also a specific question about HTML and how it gets read. Anyone with a similar question for various reasons can look at this question and learn about Empty Attribute Syntax. Specific code is being referenced here - I think this belongs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it's the same: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2

> Empty attribute syntax
>
> Just the attribute name. The value is implicitly the empty string.

To me, that says that an attribute with no value is the same as having a value of empty string.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949632/for-which-html5-attributes-is-the-empty-attribute-syntax-allowed) answer says the same.

Comment: Ahh, googling 'Empty attribute syntax' was very helpful - I've never used that phrase before. Here's another good post w/ a link to a validator to test which attributes can be used this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32949851/6647188
Thanks KarlReid!

Comment: I didn't know it either before today, I guess I just got lucky with my googling and found good information.