# Accessibility: alt or alt="" for decorative images

Tags: html, wcag2.0

In terms of [WCAG 2.0 accessibility](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H37.html), is an empty alt-tag equally valid if it's written `alt` or `alt=""` in the html?
Like this:

```
 <img src="some-image.jpg" alt="">

 <img src="some-image.jpg" alt>
```

Are they both valid for stating decorative images?

Inspecting an image with `alt=""` in a browser's DevTools will display `alt`, so is it valid to just write `alt` in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both should be treated equally.

According to the [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2):

> **Empty attribute syntax**
>
> Just the attribute name. The value is implicitly the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44764507/18717610
A screen reader will not read the image with an empty alt attribute.